# Regular Expression to allow 1 Letter and 1 Number

Tags: regex

Hi I want a regular expression that will just allow **ONE** letter(which can be any from A-Z in upper or lower case and then **ONE** numeric between(1-9)

Correct values are

```
T5
e3
k8
Z2
```

Incorrect Values are

```
Aa1
12
aa
rr
4r
1w
```

Thanks.

Comment: So trivial, read a bit about regexp and you'll find.

Answer (score 5):

you should explore regex before asking this question [***quick tutorial***](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

by the way this regex works for you

```
^[a-zA-Z][1-9]$
```

`^` for start of string

`$` for end of string

you can use according to your need

Answer (score 4):

try use this regex `\b[a-zA-Z][1-9]\b`

Comment: Correct, if the goal is to find these numbers in a larger string (as opposed to validating an entire string). Since the OP didn't specify what he intends to do precisely, +1.